Cannot access alternate domain address through CloudFront distribution
I am currently hosting my website on an S3 bucket, I have GitHub actions and an IAM user updating the bucket whenever theres an update. I am using Cloudfront for content delivery and the generic xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net domain works. However I have a custom domain that I assigned as an alternate domain that does not work. I've been trying to fix this for the last two days but had no luck.
P.s I do have an A record made since its a root domain and my SSL certificate is us-east-1
Let me know if you guys have any questions
